# Prune sklearn decision tree to ensure monotony

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I need to prune a sklearn decision tree classifier in such a way that the indicated probability (the value on the right in the image) is monotonous increasing. For example, if you program a basic tree in python, you have:

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
from sklearn.tree._tree import TREE_LEAF
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
 
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data[:, 0].reshape(-1,1), np.where(iris.target==0,0,1)
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3, random_state=123)
tree.fit(X,y)
percentages = tree.tree_.value[:,0,1]/np.sum(tree.tree_.value.reshape(-1,2), axis=1)
```

Now the leaves that do not follow the monotony, as indicated must be eliminated.
[image]

remaining as follows:

[image]

Although the indicated example does not show it, a rule to consider is that **if the leaves have different parents, then the leave with the largest amount of data is kept**. To deal with this I have been trying to do a brute force algorithm, but it only performs the first iteration and i need apply the algorithm for bigger trees. The answer is probably using recursion, but with the sklearn tree structure, I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performing the following sustains the pruning requirements you suggested: A traversal on the tree, identification of non-monotonic leaves, each time removing the non-monotonic leaves of the parent node with least members and repeating this until the monotonicity between leaves is sustained. Even though this each-time-remove-one-node approach adds time complexity, the trees usually have limited depth. The conference paper ["Pruning for Monotone Classification Trees"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-45231-7_1) helped me understand the monotonicity in trees. Then I have derived this approach to sustain your scenario.

Since the need is to identify non-monotonic leaves from left to right, the first step is to [post-order traverse the tree](https://www.techiedelight.com/postorder-tree-traversal-iterative-recursive/). If you are not familiar with tree traversals, this is completely normal. I suggest understanding the mechanics of it via studying from the Internet sources before understanding the function. You could run the traversal function to see its findings. Practical output will help you understand.

```
#We will define a traversal algorithm which will scan the nodes and leaves from left to right
#The traversal is recursive, we declare global lists to collect values from each recursion
traversal=[] #List to collect traversal steps
parents=[]#List to collect the parents of the collected nodes or leaves
is_leaves=[] #List to collect if the collected traversal item are leaves or not
# A function to do postorder tree traversal
def postOrderTraversal(tree,root,parent):
    if root!=-1:
        #Recursion on left child
        postOrderTraversal(tree,tree.tree_.children_left[root],root)
        #Recursion on right child
        postOrderTraversal(tree,tree.tree_.children_right[root],root)  
        traversal.append(root) #Collect the name of node or leaf
        parents.append(parent) #Collect the parent of the collected node or leaf
        is_leaves.append(is_leaf(tree,root)) #Collect if the collected object is leaf
```

Above, we call the left and right children of nodes with recursion, this is via the provided methods of the [decision tree structure](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#understanding-the-decision-tree-structure). The used `is_leaf()` is a helper function as below.

```
def is_leaf(tree,node):
  if tree.tree_.children_left[node]==-1:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

The decision tree nodes always have two leaves. Therefore checking only the existence of left child yields the information whether object in question is a node or leaf. The tree returns -1 if the child asked does not exist.

As you have defined the non-monotonicity condition, the ratios of classes of 1 within leaves are required. I have called this `positive_ratio()` (This is what you called "percentages".)

```
def positive_ratio(tree): #The frequency of 1 values of leaves in binary classification tree: 
  #Number of samples with value 1 in leaves/total number of samples in nodes/leaves
  return tree.tree_.value[:,0,1]/np.sum(tree.tree_.value.reshape(-1,2), axis=1)
```

The final helper function below returns the tree index of the node (1,2,3 etc.) with the minimum number of samples. This function requires the list of nodes of which leaves exhibit non-monotonic behavior. We call `n_node_samples` property of tree structure within this helper function. The found node is the node to remove its leaves.

```
def min_samples_node(tree, nodes): #Finds the node with the minimum number of samples among the provided list
  #Make a dictionary of number of samples of given nodes, and their index in the nodes list
  samples_dict={tree.tree_.n_node_samples[node]:i for i,node in enumerate(nodes)}
  min_samples=min(samples_dict.keys()) #The minimum number of samples among the samples of nodes
  i_min=samples_dict[min_samples] #Index of the node with minimum number of samples
  return nodes[i_min] #The number of node with the minimum number of samples
```

After defining the helper functions, the wrapper function that performs the pruning iterates until the monotonicity of the tree is sustained. Desired monotonic tree is returned.

```
def prune_nonmonotonic(tree): #Prune non-monotonic nodes of a binary classification tree
  while True: #Repeat until monotonicity is sustained
    #Clear the traversal lists for a new scan
    traversal.clear()
    parents.clear()
    is_leaves.clear()
    #Do a post-order traversal of tree so that the leaves will be returned in order from left to right
    postOrderTraversal(tree,0,None)
    #Filter the traversal outputs by keeping only leaves and leaving out the nodes
    leaves=[traversal[i] for i,leaf in enumerate(is_leaves) if leaf == True]
    leaves_parents=[parents[i] for i,leaf in enumerate(is_leaves) if leaf == True]
    pos_ratio=positive_ratio(tree) #List of positive samples ratio of the nodes of binary classification tree
    leaves_pos_ratio=[pos_ratio[i] for i in leaves] #List of positive samples ratio of the traversed leaves
    #Detect the non-monotonic pairs by comparing the leaves side-by-side
    nonmonotone_pairs=[[leaves[i],leaves[i+1]] for i,ratio in enumerate(leaves_pos_ratio[:-1]) if (ratio>=leaves_pos_ratio[i+1])]
    #Make a flattened and unique list of leaves out of pairs
    nonmonotone_leaves=[]
    for pair in nonmonotone_pairs:
      for leaf in pair:
        if leaf not in nonmonotone_leaves:
          nonmonotone_leaves.append(leaf)
    if len(nonmonotone_leaves)==0: #If all leaves show monotonic properties, then break
      break
    #List the parent nodes of the non-monotonic leaves
    nonmonotone_leaves_parents=[leaves_parents[i] for i in [leaves.index(leave) for leave in nonmonotone_leaves]]
    node_min=min_samples_node(tree, nonmonotone_leaves_parents) #The node with minimum number of samples
    #Prune the tree by removing the children of the detected non-monotonic and lowest number of samples node
    tree.tree_.children_left[node_min]=-1
    tree.tree_.children_right[node_min]=-1
  return tree
```

The all containing "while" loop continues until the iteration where traversed leaves exhibit non-monotonicity no more. The `min_samples_node()` identifies the node which contains non-monotonic leaves, and it is the lowest membered among alike. When its left and right children are replaced with the value "-1", the tree is pruned and the next "while" iteration will yield a completely different tree traversal to identify and remove the remaining non-monotonicity.

The below images show the unpruned and pruned trees, respectively.

[image: The unpruned tree]
[image: The pruned tree]

Comment: excellent answer, I ended up doing something similar filling a list with sheets and their respective parents. Thanks for your help :)